# Numbering with CSS Counter for Headings

Tags: html, css, css-counter

I'm trying to achieve a css counting for headers.
for ex.

```
<h1>first heading</h1>
<h2>second heading</h2>
```

will be converted

```
1. first heading
1.1 second heading
```

That works fine with the css counter. What doesn't work is when the h2 is a h3. The result will be that the h3 heading will add a "1.0.1" instead of a 1.1.1, because there is no h2 heading so the counter for h2 is 0.

```
<h1>first heading</h1>
<h3>third heading (should be 1.1.1)</h3>
```

will be converted

```
1. first heading
1.0.1 third heading (should be 1.1.1)
```

Any suggestion how to solve this (is it even possible)

ps. an example for the headings can be found here http://jsfiddle.net/6xpveu0t/

Comment: why do you skip headline-2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Please use headlines in semantically correct way.

In the earlier days, people rather misused different headline-tags to suit their design, rather than styling them correctly as it is done today (hopefully everywhere).

In terms of **semantic usage of headlines**, a headline 1 is always followed by a headline 2 followed by a headline 3. You may refer to [w3c school about headline priority](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_headings.asp).

In printed books, you will never find a nested subchapter inside a *skipped* chapter. Therefore the CSS counter is correct.

Nevertheless you can include an empty `<h2></h2>`.